# Replace constant in summation function using replace or If or /

Tags: function-construction, replacement, summation, assignment

Hi i how do i replace constant for k in this summation.

For following:

1. Even 2*n  Even replace k by a
2. Even 2*n+1 Odd replace k by b

   [image]

**Here is the code**

```
ue[x_, t_, k_, n_] := 
           (1/2)*Sum[Subscript[k, j]*(Subscript[x, j - 1][t] - Subscript[x, j][t])^2,{j, 1, n + 1}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Subscript[k, j_?EvenQ] = a;
Subscript[k, j_?OddQ] = b;
```

For extra conditions at $j=0$ and $j=n+1$ you can use a two-index form $k_{n,j}$:

```
Subscript[k, n_, 0] = 0;
Subscript[k, n_, j_] /; j == n + 1 = 0;
Subscript[k, n_, j_?EvenQ] = a;
Subscript[k, n_, j_?OddQ] = b;
```

Check:

```
With[{n = 10}, Table[Subscript[k, n, j], {j, 0, n + 1}]]
```

> {0, b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a, 0}

Comment: sir how do i impose extra condition beside that above that k=0 at j=0 and j=n+1;
k[0] = 0;
k[n + 1] = 0;

Comment: ok i got it sir. thanks

Comment: Subscript[k, j_?EvenQ] = a;
Subscript[k, j_?OddQ] = b;

    "to impose extra condition on beside that above that k=0 at j=0 and j=n+1;
      use " for n=4;

    Subscript[k, 0] = 0;
    Subscript[k, 4] = 0;